# Getting Auth guard [web] is not defined in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to use web session for authentication in Lumen. Somewhere i found that I can use

```
Auth::guard('web')->login(compact('username','password'))
```

for login but it is giving defined error:

> Getting Auth guard [web] is not

Let me know if I am missing something or doing it wrong? I want to know how to use session based authentication in Lumen

Comment: Have you defined a web guard in `config/auth.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your default guard to web

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete Laravel framework instead. Lumen specifically does not come with session support; it is for stateless APIs.

> "Since Lumen does not support session state, incoming requests that you wish to authenticate must be authenticated via a stateless mechanism such as API tokens."

[Lumen 6.x Docs - Authentication - Introduction](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)